# XPath with XPath operators

Tags: xpath

I am interested in finding if there is a way to add an XPath as part of operand while evaluating another XPath.

Consider the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookStore>
    <bestSellerId>3</bestSellerId>
    <book>
        <bookId>1</bookId>
        <bookName>First Book</bookName>
        <bookAuthor>First Author</bookAuthor>
    </book>
    <book>
        <bookId>2</bookId>
        <bookName>Second Book</bookName>
        <bookAuthor>Second Author</bookAuthor>
    </book>
    <book>
        <bookId>3</bookId>
        <bookName>Third Book</bookName>
        <bookAuthor>Third Author</bookAuthor>
    </book>
    <book>
        <bookId>4</bookId>
        <bookName>Fouth Book</bookName>
        <bookAuthor>Fouth Author</bookAuthor>
    </book>
</bookStore>
```

I need to fetch the `bookAuthor` of the bestseller which can be determined using the `bestSellerId`.

I am trying the following but am not getting any match:

```
bookStore/book[bookId=bookStore/bestSellerId/text()]/bookAuthor
```

Answer (score 1):

You were just missing a `/` to get to the root node.
So your expression should look like this:

```
bookStore/book[bookId=/bookStore/bestSellerId/text()]/bookAuthor
```

The output is:

```
Third Author
```

Comment: Following up further on the above, this does not seem to work if bestSelletId is blank like <bestSellerId/ >. I want to now select all book nodes which have blank bookId when bestSellerId is blank.

Comment: If you have another question, raise it as a new question, not as a comment on the answer to your first question.